# Mongoose how can I get a list of conversations, a sepcific user has chatted with?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Ok, so basically my data model looks like this:

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    to: { type: String, required: true},
    from: { type: String, required: true},
    message: { type: String, required: true}
});
```

What I want to do is have a function I can just pass in the username of the current logged in user: example billy.

The database might contain 100's of messages like this:

```
[{"_id":"2394290384","from":"billy","to":"dan","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290384","from":"dan","to":"billy","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290389","from":"john","to":"billy","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290389","from":"billy","to":"john","message":"some message"}]
```

It should just give me an output like this:

```
 [{"_id":"2394290384","from":"billy","to":"dan","message":"some message"},   
  {"_id":"2394290389","from":"john","to":"billy","message":"some message"}]
```

How can I just pull the latest 1 for each of those messages.

So it basically shows 1 result per conversation / person I have had a chat with regardless of if I sent them a message or they sent me a message.

It should just pull up 1 result per conversation with the all the data related to their latest message.

So the latest message, the id for that message, the user it was to and from.

So that I can create a conversation list on 1 side which shows the users and their message below their name. the user clicks on it and it shows the chat.

I have asked multiple variations of this question trying to figure it out and I have been un successful so far in finding a solution for this.

I come from a php mysql background so I am new to node and mongoose.

Thank you for all your help in advance I really appreciate it.

I have already mentioned why the 2 items in the example are distinct. It is pulling 1 result per conversation based on the current logged in username.

So there needs to be a function like this:

```
getconversations(username){
Message.find(Where messages are to this username or from this from username).exec(function(error,results){
this would probably output all messages like so:
[{"_id":"2394290384","from":"billy","to":"dan","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290384","from":"dan","to":"billy","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290389","from":"john","to":"billy","message":"some message"},
 {"_id":"2394290389","from":"billy","to":"john","message":"some message"}] 


})
}

if the current username was billy.

    But I only want 1 of the latest.

    So i can have a list on the left:
    messages:
    username:
    lastmessage
    username:
    last message

    a user clicks on it and it opens up the full chat. For example like you see on skype on ios or android: it shows you a list of users and their message below. you tap on it and it shows you the chat. it is basically pulling that list based on people you have had a conversation with.
```

How I finally got it working:

```
var user="billy";
Message.aggregate(
    {
           $match: {
              $or: [{
                to: user
              }, 
              {
                from: user
              }]
            }
        },
    { $project: { "from" : {
      $cond: {'if': {$eq: ['$to',user]},'then': '$from', 'else': '$to'}
                            },
                            "to":{
      $cond: {'if': {$eq: ['$to',user]},'then': '$to', 'else': '$from'}
                            },
                            "message":"$message"



                } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $group: { "id": { "$first" : "$_id" },"_id" : { "from" : "$from" }, "from": { "$first" : "$from" },"to": { "$first" : "$to" }, "message": { "$first" : "$message" }  } }
, function(err, docs) {
  res.send(docs);

});
```

It searches by a specific username and strips all duplicates and just outputs the 1 record per user and outputs their message, id, to and from

Comment: To clarify why you are yet to be upvoted on a single question and other comments I have given to you, what you really need to explain here is why? Meaning out of the sample you have given, why do the two items you point to come out as "distinct"? People will not answer your questions if you do not accept them. And people won't waste their time given the former and a lack of a reasonable explaintion for your results. It is up to you to explain yourself. Remember. Busy reputable colleagues. Explain yourself clearly and then you will learn.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is how do you perform an `or` query in Mongodb from Mongoose?

```
var Message = mongoose.model('message');
Message.find({ $or: [ { from: 'billy' }, { to: 'billy' } ] }, function(err, docs) {
    // docs will now be an array of Message models
});
```

Update:
You can order by `_id` as its based on time inserted and then limit results to one record:

```
var Message = mongoose.model('message');
Message.find({ $or: [ { from: 'billy' }, { to: 'billy' } ] })
    .sort({ _id : -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function(err, docs) {
    // docs will now be an array containing 1 Message model
});
```

Update 2:
Try using the aggregation framework:

```
var Message = mongoose.model('message');
Message.aggregate(
    { $project: { "from" : "$from", "message" : "$message" } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $group: { "_id" : { "from" : "$from" }, "from": { "$first" : "$from" }, "message": { "$first" : "$message" } } }
, function(err, docs) {
    /* i.e. docs = array
    [ 
        { "_id" : { "from" : "alex" }, "from" : "alex", "message" : "Some message" },
        { "_id" : { "from" : "billy" }, "from" : "billy", "message" : "Some message" },
    ...

    */
});
```

Comment: works and the output is like so:
[{"_id":{"from":"dan"},"from":"dan","message":"hello"},{"_id":{"from":"nasser"},"from":"nasser","message":"wow"},{"_id":{"from":"billy"},"from":"billy","message":"bye"}]

Any way to format it a bit better im not sure what the weird curly brackets are around {from:"billly"}
and theres no ids

Comment: Thanks, Could you accept the answer ;)

the _id is there as its a unique index. If you require the index of each document, just add `"id": { "$first" : "$_id" }` to the `$group` object

Comment: Where can I pass in the current users username? so it only pulls records to and from him? and I cant seem to get the value of to.

when i add "to": { "$first" : "$to" } it just returns null

Comment: I got the to thing working sorry my bad. How can I return all for 1 specific user so its not just outputting the whole database.

Comment: Also is there anyway to do an equivalent of skip and limit for pagination on an aggregate like a mysql query?

Comment: I found out its not really working and still has duplicates, proof:
[{"_id":{"from":"dan"},"id":"5443fc4f1f43f217047d8932","from":"dan","to":"nas","message":"hello"},{"_id":{"from":"nas"},"id":"5443ffe33f11d43604f042a9","from":"nas","to":"dan","message":"something"},{"_id":{"from":"billy"},"id":"5443fff2739cc33704c30171","from":"billy","to":"nas","message":"bye"}]

Its still outs 2 rows for messages to and from dan :/
the first 2 rows are duplicates.